# Leaflet - problem with syntax with plugin to fill geojson polygon with png pattern

Tags: leaflet, polygon, fill

I'm using this plugin https://github.com/lwsu/leaflet-polygon-fillPattern to fill my geojson polygons with .png pattern.

It works great when I use the basic syntax, i.e :

```
L.polygon(poly1, {fill:'url(image.gif)'}).addTo(map);
```

But I'd like to grab value from geojson properties to change the fill pattern.

so far, i'm using this syntax where pattern value is stored in

> feature.properties.PolygonFill

I tied this syntax :

```
L.polygon(poly1, {
fill:'url('+feature.properties.PolygonFill+')'
}).addTo(map);
```

But returned value is null and no image is displayed.

Any idea of what is wrong ?

Comment: Hard to say without looking at a more complete example with maybe a bit of your GeoJSON data.

Comment: Hi Ivan. I think it is just a problem of syntax. For a given image named image.gif, the piece of code {fill:'url(image.gif)'} works but if I replace image.gif by a variable named imageFill = image.gif -> fill:'url('+imageFill+')' it works af if the variable = 0